# How to enforce constness over template type?

Tags: c++, templates, constants

```
template<typename T> struct SomeClass{

    void someFunc(const T& data) const {}

};

void testFunc(const int* a) {

    SomeClass<int*> some_class;

    some_class.someFunc( a);

}
```

I made a template instance with a non-const type. Now when calling a certain function I get errors that say:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’
note: initializing argument 1 of ‘void SomeClass<T>::someFunc(const T&) const [with T = int*]’
```

So basically my `const T&` is treated as plain `T&`, the `const` is ignored. Why? How can I make sure in this case that it is seen by the compiler as `const T&`?

Comment: When you have a `T` that's an "`int *`". A `const T` is ***not*** a "`const int *`". It is a "`int * const`". That's where your type mismatch comes from. Welcome to C++. As far as what to do about it, this is unclear to me, due to lack of detail in the question. Can't say without seeing more detail.

Comment: @jesperjuhl how can you make a non member function const???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider to partial specialize your class template `SomeClass` for the case `T` is a pointer. Then, add `const` to the type pointed to instead of the pointer itself (i.e., *pointer to const* instead of *const pointer*):

```
template<typename T> struct SomeClass<T*> {
   void someFunc(const T* &data) const { /* ... */ } 
};
```

`SomeClass<int*>::someFunc()` (i.e., `T = int*`) will be instantiated to:

```
void someFunc(const int* &data) const;
```

`data` above is a reference to a pointer to `const int`. However, with your primary template, `SomeClass<int*>::someFunc()` is actually:

```
void someFunc(int* const &data) const;
```

That is, `data` here is a reference to a `const` pointer to `int`. Therefore, you can't pass `a`, which is a `const int*`, as an argument to `someFunc()` since that pointed `const int` would be modifiable through the parameter `data`. In other words, the constness would be lost.

Comment: Thank you! My problem with this is that the class in the real-life code is HUGE. Is there some smart way to make this work without having to copy-paste all the code?

Comment: @Newline I've added another new answer that may solve the problem you are facing. I hope it can solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your definition to `SomeClass<const int*> some_class;`. The `T` comes from the definition and is `int*`, compiler is complaining rightfully.

Comment: Thank you! Does this mean there is no way to tell to compiler to "use the same type as T, except make sure it is const"? I know there is a way to remove the const (`typename std::remove_const<T>::type`) but not the other way

Comment: There's also an `add_const` IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` is not ignored. It's applied to the type `int*`, yielding an `int*` that cannot be modified, i.e., `int* const`. In `const int*`, the `const` applies to the `int`, not to the pointer. That is, `const int*` points at an `int` that cannot be modified.

Inside `testFunc` you end up **both** consts. Since it's called with a `const int*`, the specialization of `SomeClass` has to be `SomeClass<const int*>`. And then when you call  `someFunc` you get the second one; the actual argument type is `const int* const`. The first `const` applies to the `int` and the second `const` applies to the argument itself, i.e., to the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the code base is huge and therefore you can't afford to write a specialization for your class template, you could provide the following *delegating* member template, `someFunc()`, which is an overload of your original member function:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> struct SomeClass {
   // your original member function
   void someFunc(const T &data) const { /* ... a lot of stuff ... */ } 

   // delegating member template
   template<typename S>
   void someFunc(const S* &data) const {
      // delegate to original function
      someFunc(const_cast<S*>(data));
   }
};
```

First, this member template only comes into play with pointer arguments. Second, what it really does is to delegate the call to your original member function with the same name by casting out the `const` from the pointed type.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! Currently, when I try to use it with non-pointer `int` it says `error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’` but I will figure something out.

Comment: I've just simplified it. What I meant is that the member template is only considered for pointer arguments. If you pass an `int` as an argument (e.g., instead of an `int *`), then only the remaining member function, your original `someFunc()`, is considered. If this member function is not suitable, then it results in a compile error since there are no other options left.